# How can I programmatically load and display all available blocks?

Tags: 8, blocks

```
$block = Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($block_id);
ksm($block);
```

This code loads only one specific block. But how can I load and display **all** available blocks?

Answer (score 6):

Using the service plugin.manager.block we will get all blocks available definition.

```
$blockManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');

$contextRepository = \Drupal::service('context.repository');

// Get blocks definition

$definitions = $blockManager->getDefinitionsForContexts($contextRepository->getAvailableContexts());
```

To get details about one specific block you can use below code.

```
print_r($definitions['help_block']);
```

Comment: how can we limit the list of block here.

Comment: I wish there was a drush command for that

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$blocks = Drupal\block\Entity\Block::loadMultiple();
ksm($blocks);
```

Comment: This will help you find all the pluginIds you can then use: function _helper_block_build_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) {
  if($block->getPluginId() === "webform_block"){
    dd($block);
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

The core block module using "getFilteredDefinitions" method to list the blocks

```
$blockManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
$contextRepository = \Drupal::service('context.repository');

// Get blocks definition
$definitions = $blockManager->getFilteredDefinitions('block_ui', $contextRepository->getAvailableContexts());

print_r($definitions);
```

Comment: Can you please suggest how can we use `getFilteredDefinitions` to return just the content blocks (the ones created from the Blocks UI) and are visible on a given URL or a content type?

Answer (score -2):

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('block_content');
$ids  = $query->execute();
```

You can also use 'block' instead of 'block_content' to get blocks from code